# Podium CSS: position elements at the bottom of their div

Tags: html, css, position, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a podium using CSS and HTML. I have achieved to positionate the steps of the podium at the bottom by adding `position: relative` to the father and `position: absolute; bottom: 0` to the steps, but as I want to display a text just above the steps, I'm having problems positioning this text there.

My first aproach was to put the text and the step on a div and positioning absolutely this div, but as the steps get their height by a percentage of their father the father needs to have a `height: 100%` property, so the div solution isn't valid.

Here I attach my code snippet:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: DaggerSquare;
    src: url("fonts/podium-font.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/podium-font.ttf")  format("truetype");
}

#podium-box {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.podium-number {
 font-family: DaggerSquare;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 4em;
 color: white;
}

.step-container {
 width: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

.step {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}

.bg-blue {
 background-color: #063b65;
}

#first-step {
 height: 50%;
}

#second-step {
 height: 35%;
}

#third-step {
 height: 30%;
}

.centerBoth {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="import" type="css" href="podium-chart.css">

<div id="podium-box" class="row" style="height: 400px">
 <div class="col-md-4 step-container m-0 p-0">
  <div>
   Text 2
  </div>
  <div id="second-step" class="bg-blue step centerBoth podium-number">
   2 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 step-container m-0 p-0">
  <div>
   Text 1
  </div>
  <div id="first-step" class="bg-blue step centerBoth podium-number">
   1
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 step-container m-0 p-0">
  <div>
   Text 3
  </div>
  <div id="third-step" class="bg-blue step centerBoth podium-number">
   3
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please use the HTML/CSS/JS Snippet from Stackoverflow for us to be able to copy/run your code.

Comment: @robinvrd Sorry I thought it displayed automatically. How can I add it to the question?

Comment: you have a button in the editor next to the bold, underline, ..., link, code, etc buttons.

Comment: you are defining `width: 100%` on `.step-container` which is `col-md-4` (which means setting width at 1/3 of the page), firstly this has no sense. I will propose you an answer from scratch.

Comment: Thank you, now you can run the snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `position:absolute` just use flexbox and flex-columns.

Then push the text div to the bottom.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: DaggerSquare;
  src: url("fonts/podium-font.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/podium-font.ttf") format("truetype");
}

#podium-box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.podium-number {
  font-family: DaggerSquare;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: white;
}

.step-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.step-container>div:first-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.step {
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #063b65;
}

#first-step {
  height: 50%;
}

#second-step {
  height: 35%;
}

#third-step {
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="import" type="css" href="podium-chart.css">

<div id="podium-box" class="row" style="height: 300px">
  <div class="col-md-4 step-container m-0 p-0">
    <div>
      Text 2
    </div>
    <div id="second-step" class="bg-blue step centerBoth podium-number">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 step-container m-0 p-0">
    <div>
      Text 1
    </div>
    <div id="first-step" class="bg-blue step centerBoth podium-number">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 step-container m-0 p-0">
    <div>
      Text 3
    </div>
    <div id="third-step" class="bg-blue step centerBoth podium-number">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was asking for. Thank you so much for your answer and the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, you could probably start from scratch and structure this a bit better. But if you want to keep as is then just give the divs that contain the text a class and give them the following attributes:

```
 position:absolute;
 bottom:70px;
```